# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object - Tomcat 8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, classloader

I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.<clinit>(Ejb3Configuration.java:142)
            at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:55)
            at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
```

Why? There are two jars containing the class Logger. The jars are:

-jboss-logging-spi and jboss-logging

Jboss-logging-spi.jar is a transitive dependency of the jbosscache-core.jar and unfortunately it gets loaded first by Tomcat 8.

What is the best way to fix this? Is it possible to control the order in which the .jars are loaded by Tomcat?

Additional information:

-The current .war file which I can't get it working on the new server(Ubuntu) it is working on the old server(OpenSuse).

Comment: It is possible though not recommended to attempt to order JAR file loading. Why are you using two incompatible .class definitions? It seems like you need to have all your libraries agreeing on the versions being used.

Comment: It is a legacy system. I don't have control over it. The .war is working in a old server but I cannot get it working on a new server that I am installing. Do you know why? Because the jars have been loaded in a different order in Tomcat. This way I would like to give precedence to a certain jar. Could you tell me how to do it please?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to fix this?

Eliminate the duplicate classes. *Period*. There's no other recommendation. Masking the problem through class loading order will have a similar problem pop up later, making maintenance harder next time.

One application should *never* contain two conflicting implementations (or even two identical implementations) of the same class. If one of the classes is on the (appserver-) global classpath: Remove it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit JAR-ordering can be accomplished in Tomcat via abusing the `resources` facility in Tomcat. I'm not going to give a complete answer, here, because (a) it's highly non-recommended and (b) you'd better really know what you are doing in order to do it.

So, briefly:

1. Read all about [resources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/resources.html)
2. Use `<PreResources>` to force a library or libraries to the front of the line
3. Reconsider whether you really want to do this, or just fix the initial problem